# Absolute system paths in js from output bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I use this repo: https://github.com/ReactJSResources/react-webpack-babel

After building production package with `npm run build`, I opened produced js file and found absolute system paths like this:

`t.register(a,"default","D:/texts/Sources/react-webpack-babel/src/components/Sample.jsx")`

Why are there absolute paths? How can I remove/fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, this [has been fixed in the new release](https://github.com/ReactJSResources/react-webpack-babel/issues/321#issuecomment-419917564).